# Explicit construction of entity type '###' in query is not allowed.

Tags: linq-to-sql

Using Linq commands and Linq To SQL datacontext, Im trying to instance an Entity called "Produccion" from my datacontext in this way:

```
Demo.View.Data.PRODUCCION pocoProduccion = 
(
    from m in db.MEDICOXPROMOTORs
    join a in db.ATENCIONs on m.cmp equals a.cmp
    join e in db.EXAMENXATENCIONs on a.numeroatencion equals e.numeroatencion
    join c in db.CITAs on e.numerocita equals c.numerocita
    where e.codigo == codigoExamenxAtencion
    select new Demo.View.Data.PRODUCCION
    {
         cmp = a.cmp,
         bonificacion = comi,
         valorventa = precioEstudio,
         codigoestudio = lblCodigoEstudio.Content.ToString(),
         codigopaciente = Convert.ToInt32(lblCodigoPaciente.Content.ToString()),
         codigoproduccion = Convert.ToInt32(lblNroInforme.Content.ToString()),
         codigopromotor = m.codigopromotor,
         fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()),
         numeroinforme = Convert.ToInt32(lblNroInforme.Content.ToString()),
         revisado = false,
         codigozona = (c.codigozona.Value == null ? Convert.ToInt32(c.codigozona) : 0),
         codigoclinica = Convert.ToInt32(c.codigoclinica),
         codigoclase = e.codigoclase,
    }
).FirstOrDefault();
```

While executing the above code, I'm getting the following error that the stack trace is included:

```
System.NotSupportedException was caught
  Message="The explicit construction of the entity type 'Demo.View.Data.PRODUCCION' in a query is not allowed."
  Source="System.Data.Linq"
  StackTrace:
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression init)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression selector)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitFirst(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression lambda, Boolean isFirst)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
       en System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
       en System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
       en System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
       en Demo.View.InformeMedico.realizarProduccionInforme(Int32 codigoExamenxAtencion, Double precioEstudio, Int32 comi) en D:\cs_InformeMedico\app\InformeMedico.xaml.cs:línea 602
       en Demo.View.InformeMedico.UpdateEstadoEstudio(Int32 codigo, Char state) en D:\cs_InformeMedico\app\InformeMedico.xaml.cs:línea 591
       en Demo.View.InformeMedico.btnGuardar_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) en D:\cs_InformeMedico\app\InformeMedico.xaml.cs:línea 683
  InnerException:
```

Is that now allowed in LINQ2SQL?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Entities can be created outside of queries and inserted into the data store using a DataContext. You can then retrieve them using queries. However, you can't create entities as part of a query.

Comment: How can I pass the select values from that returning query to an Entity, I mean dont using members, just like "varReturningQuery as ProductionEntity"?

Answer (score 15):

I am finding this limitation to be very annoying, and going against the common trend of not using SELECT * in queries.

Still with c# anonymous types there is a workaround, by fetching the objects into an anonymous type, and then copy it over into the correct type.

For example:

```
var q = from emp in employees where emp.ID !=0
select new {Name = emp.First + " " + emp.Last, EmployeeId = emp.ID }
var r = q.ToList();
List<User> users = new List<User>(r.Select(new User
   {
        Name = r.Name,
        EmployeeId = r.EmployeeId 
   }));
```

And in the case when we deal with a single value (as in the situation described in the question) it is even easier, and we just need to copy directly the values:

```
var q = from emp in employees where emp.ID !=0 
select new { Name = emp.First + " " + emp.Last, EmployeeId = emp.ID }
var r = q.FirstOrDefault();
User user = new User { Name = r.Name, EmployeeId = r.ID };
```

If the name of the properties match the database columns we can do it even simpler in the query, by doing select

```
var q = from emp in employees where emp.ID !=0 
select new { emp.First, emp.Last, emp.ID }
```

One might go ahead and write a lambda expression that can copy automatically based on the property name, without needing to specify the values explictly.

Comment: I agree the limitation is very annoying. The call to `ToList` in your solution, however, will put the results in memory, which is probably not desirable for big data sets.

Answer (score 15):

Here's another workaround:

1. Make a class that derives from your LINQ to SQL class. I'm assuming that the L2S class that you want to return is Order:

   ```
   internal class OrderView : Order { }
   ```
2. Now write the query this way:

   ```
   var query = from o in db.Order
               select new OrderView // instead of Order
               {
                  OrderID = o.OrderID,
                  OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                  // etc.
               };
   ```
3. Cast the result back into Order, like this:

   ```
   return query.Cast<Order>().ToList(); // or .FirstOrDefault()
   ```
4. (or use something more sensible, like BLToolkit / LINQ to DB)

Note: I haven't tested to see if tracking works or not; it works to retrieve data, which is what I needed.

Comment: Brilliant! Although I didn't need to cast back

Comment: I agree this is a great solution!  If there's a technical reason why I shouldn't project onto an entity class then that's fine I won't, but who wants to redefine a new (potentially lengthy) class with the exact same shape?  No one, that's who.  This solution solves it without explicit redefinition.  Great job pbz, nailed it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer pbz!  I can't believe how slick it worked.  I'll post an example below and give credit to this answer.

Answer (score 12):

I have found that if you do a .ToList() on the query before trying to contruct new objects it works

Comment: But that loses deferred execution.

Comment: the only solution i found was that does not defer the execution.... `.Select (p => new { anonymous columns }).ToList().Select(p => new TModel { Col1 = p.Col1, etc })`

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into the same issue.

I found a very easy solution.

```
var a = att as Attachment;

Func<Culture, AttachmentCulture> make = 
    c => new AttachmentCulture { Culture = c };

var culs = from c in dc.Cultures
           let ac = c.AttachmentCultures.SingleOrDefault( 
                                           x => x.Attachment == a)
           select ac == null ? make(c) : ac;

return culs;
```

Comment: select may be better written as 

select ac ?? make(c);

Comment: Excellent solution - thanks!  Any ideas why this isn't allowed without doing this?

Comment: @Whisk - in case you're still interested, I found http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/1ce25da3-44c6-407d-8395-4c146930004b - '...Constructing entity instances manually as a projection pollutes the cache with potentially malformed objects...'

Answer (score 6):

I construct an anonymous type, use IEnumerable (which preserves deferred execution), and then re-consruct the datacontext object.  Both Employee and Manager are datacontext objects:

```
    var q = dc.Employees.Where(p => p.IsManager == 1)
            .Select(p => new { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name })
            .AsEnumerable()    
            .Select(item => new Manager() { Id = item.Id, Name = item.Name });
```

Comment: Wouldn't `AsEnumerable` cause eager loading?

Answer (score 0):

Within the book "70-515 Web Applications Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4 - Self paced training kit", page 638 has the following example to output results to a strongly typed object:

```
    IEnumerable<User> users = from emp in employees where emp.ID !=0
    select new User
    {
    Name = emp.First + " " + emp.Last,
    EmployeeId = emp.ID
    }
```

Mark Pecks advice appears to contradict this book - however, for me this example still displays the above error as well, leaving me somewhat confused. Is this linked to version differences? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: The above example works if "User" is not part of the DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

I found another workaround for the problem that even lets you retain your result as IQueryale, so it doesn't actually execute the query until you want it to be executed (like it would with the ToList() method).

So linq doesn't allow you to create an entity as a part of query? You can shift that task to the database itself and create a function that will grab the data you want. After you import the function to your data context, you just need to set the result type to the one you want.

---

I found out about this when I had to write a piece of code that would produce a `IQueryable<T>` in which the items don't actually exist in the table containing T.

Answer (score 0):

pbz posted a work around by creating a View class inherited from an entity class that you could be working with.  I'm working with a dbml model of a table that has > 200 columns.  When I try and return the whole table I get "Root Element missing" errors. I couldn't find anyone who wanted to deal with my particular issue so I was looking at rewriting my entire approach.  Just creating a view class for the entitiy class worked in my case.

As pbz suggests : Create a view class that inherits from your entity class.  For me this is tbCamp so :

```
    internal class tbCampView : tbCamp
    {

    }
```

Then use the view class in your query :

```
using (var dc = ConnectionClass.Connect(Dev))
        {
            var camps = dc.tbCamps.Select(s => new tbCampView
            {
                active = s.active,
                idCamp = s.idCamp,
                campName = s.campName
            });

            
            SmartTableViewer(camps, dg1);
        }

private void SmartTableViewer<T>(IEnumerable<T> allRecords)
    {
        // Build sorted rows back into new table
        var table = new DataTable();

        // Create columns based on type
        if (allRecords is IEnumerable<tbCamp> tbCampRecords)
        {
            // Get the columns you want
            table.Columns.Add("idCamp");
            table.Columns.Add("campName");

            foreach (var record in tbCampRecords)
            {
                
                // Make a new row
                var r = table.NewRow();

                // Add the contents to each column of the row
                r["idCamp"] = record.idCamp;
                r["campName"] = record.campName;

                // Add the row to the table.
                table.Rows.Add(r);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unhandled type.  Add support for new data type in SmartTableViewer()");
            return;
        }

        // Update table in grid
        dg1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
    }
```

Here is what happens when you try and create an entity class object in the query.

[image]

I didn't want to have to use an anonymous type if I could help it because I wanted the type to be tbCamp.  Since tbCampView is of type tbCamp the is operator works well. see Brian Hasden's answer [Passing a generic List<> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051067/passing-a-generic-list-in-c-sharp)

I'm surprised this is even an issue but with larger tables I run into this error so I thought I would just show it here :

When trying to read this table into memory I get the following error.  There are < 2000 rows but the columns are > 200 for each.  I don't know if that is an issue or not.

[image: Root element is missing]

If I just want a few columns I need to create a custom class and handle that which isn't that big of a pain.  With the approach pbz provided I don't have to worry about it.

Here is the entire project in case it helps someone.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const bool Dev = true;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGetAllCamps_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var dc = ConnectionClass.Connect(Dev))
        {
            IQueryable<tbCampView> camps = dc.tbCamps.Select(s => new tbCampView
            {
                // Project columns as needed.
                active = s.active,
                idCamp = s.idCamp,
                campName = s.campName
            });

            // pass in as a 
            SmartTableViewer(camps);
        }
    }

    private void SmartTableViewer<T>(IEnumerable<T> allRecords)
    {
        // Build sorted rows back into new table
        var table = new DataTable();

        // Create columns based on type
        if (allRecords is IEnumerable<tbCamp> tbCampRecords)
        {
            // Get the columns you want
            table.Columns.Add("idCamp");
            table.Columns.Add("campName");

            foreach (var record in tbCampRecords)
            {
                //var newRecord = record;
                // Make a new row
                var r = table.NewRow();

                // Add the contents to each column of the row
                r["idCamp"] = record.idCamp;
                r["campName"] = record.campName;

                // Add the row to the table.
                table.Rows.Add(r);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unhandled type.  Add support for new data type in SmartTableViewer()");
            return;
        }

        // Update table in grid
        dg1.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
    }

    internal class tbCampView : tbCamp
    {

    
    }
```

`}`