# trying to combine two similar user controls using generics

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I saw the following [here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051081/139698)

```
void SomeMethod<T>(List<T> someList)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(c1))
    {
         // etc
    }
}
```

I was trying to incorporate it somehow in the following. I'm trying to combine two very similar user controls using generics

```
public partial class UcCustomers : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    List<Customer> _list;

    public void SetDataSource(List<Customer> customers){
        _list = customers
    }

}


public partial class UcProducts : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    List<Products> _list;

    public void SetDataSource(List<Product> products){
        _list = products
    }

}
```

Problem is, I'd like to set that member _list variable but it won't let me unless I do something like:

```
IEnumerable _list;
```

But then I can't use lambda's with that type of variable. My goal is to have a GridView User Control that has some very basic CRUD functionality.

I'm thinking the SetDataSource could accept a generic List and work with it as a member variable.

Comment: Combine how?  Can you add more code or context to your question?  If you're trying to combine code that is common to both controls, you could also look at making a base user control and then having the Customers and Products inherit from that.

Comment: Could you provide your code and specify the issue on your code to clarify the problem ?

Comment: In other words, you want something like `public void SetDataSource<T>(T dataSource)`?  Which is rather redundant I think, since it's already taking a generic List...can you give an example (pseudo-code even) of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think a generic class with constraint would be what you need. If your `Products` and `Customer` is not derived from `UserControl`, you can just modify the `where` clause.

```
 public class Uc<T> : UserControl where T : UserControl
    {
        private List<T> _list;

        public void SetDataSource(List<T> list)
        {
            _list = list;
        }
    }
```