# Explicit construction of entity type [MyClass] in query is not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

Like the title says, I have the following exception:

> Description: Event code: 3005  Event
>   message: An unhandled exception has
>   occurred.    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: NotSupportedException 
>       Exception message: Explicit construction of entity type
>   'Company.Project.Core.Domain.Friend'
>   in query is not allowed.

I am using LINQ to SQL and have the following code in my datacontext:

```
var friends2 = (
    from f in dc.Friends
    where f.MyFriendsAccountId == accountId
    where f.AccountId != accountId
    select new 
    {
        f.FriendId,
        AccountId = f.MyFriendsAccountId,
        MyFriendsAccountId = f.AccountId, 
        f.CreateDate,
        f.Timestamp
    }).Distinct();

result.AddRange(
    from o in friends2
    select new Friend()
    {
        FriendId = o.FriendId, 
        AccountId = o.AccountId, 
        CreateDate = o.CreateDate, 
        MyFriendsAccountId = o.MyFriendsAccountId, 
        Timestamp = o.Timestamp
    });
```

the final code block is throwing the error and I am pretty sure it is this statement
that is the culprit:

```
.Select( o => **new Friend**
```

How should I be reworking my code to avoid this error?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787296/explicit-construction-of-entity-type-in-query-is-not-allowed

Comment: Thanks but I am still not completely clear. I'd appreciate an illustration given my particular situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Entities that are part of the data context can not be created using a LINQ query. This is a well thought design decision of the C# team. Because the entities are newed up (manually) in the `Select` statement, this would mean that they are not tracked by the `DataContext` and this can confuse developers. On the other hand, when the DataContext would automatically *insert on submit* those newed up entities, this would be confusing as well. The only option left was communicating to the developers that this is not such a good idea to do, and that is what you saw happening.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to why it isn't working. Now, could you illustrate how to make it work? What code do I need to change? Thanks.

Comment: Change the line `result.AddRange(from o in friends2 select` to `result.AddRange(from o in friends2.ToArray() select`.

Comment: You should be cautious when doing this, as it will enumerate friends2 before creating the object in the select part of the LINQ query.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you don't have PrimaryKey set on any columns in your Friends class. That way changes won't be tracked for that class anymore, but your code will work.