# Using LINQ on ObservableCollection with GroupBy and Sum aggregate

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum, observablecollection

I have the following block of code which works fine;

```
var boughtItemsToday = (from DBControl.MoneySpent
            bought in BoughtItemDB.BoughtItems
            select bought);

BoughtItems = new ObservableCollection<DBControl.MoneySpent>(boughtItemsToday);
```

It returns data from my MoneySpent table which includes ItemCategory, ItemAmount, ItemDateTime.

I want to change it to group by ItemCategory and ItemAmount so I can see where I am spending most of my money, so I created a GroupBy query, and ended up with this;

```
var finalQuery = boughtItemsToday.AsQueryable().GroupBy(category => category.ItemCategory); 

BoughtItems = new ObservableCollection<DBControl.MoneySpent>(finalQuery);
```

Which gives me 2 errors;

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.ObservableCollection(System.Collections.Generic.List)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

And this is where I'm stuck!  How can I use the GroupBy and Sum aggregate function to get a list of my categories and the associated spend in 1 LINQ query?!

Any help/suggestions gratefully received.

Mark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.GroupBy(category => category.ItemCategory);` returns an enumerable of IGrouping objects, where the key of each IGrouping is a distinct ItemCategory value, and the value is a list of MoneySpent objects.  So, you won't be able to simply drop these groupings into an ObservableCollection as you're currently doing.

Instead, you probably want to Select each grouped result into a new MoneySpent object:

```
var finalQuery = boughtItemsToday
    .GroupBy(category => category.ItemCategory)
    .Select(grouping => new MoneySpent { ItemCategory = grouping.Key, ItemAmount = grouping.Sum(moneySpent => moneySpent.ItemAmount);

BoughtItems = new ObservableCollection<DBControl.MoneySpent>(finalQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've done exactly as you said and it appears to work as expected, however it gives me the following error "Explicit construction of entity type 'WP7_CashTrack.DBControl+MoneySpent' in query is not allowed."  Is this because the constructor thinks it has already been defined?

Comment: Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952856/explicit-construction-of-entity-type-myclass-in-query-is-not-allowed.  It looks like you might need to create a new `MoneySpentSummary`-style class that stores the category and total spent.  That might be a better design, anyways, since you wouldn't be reusing a class for a slightly different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can project each group to an anyonymous (or better yet create a new type for this) class with the properties you want:

```
var finalQuery = boughtItemsToday.GroupBy(category => category.ItemCategory);
                                 .Select(g => new 
                                  { 
                                     ItemCategory = g.Key, 
                                     Cost = g.Sum(x => x.ItemAmount)
                                  });
```

The `AsQueryable()` should not be needed at all since `boughtItemsToday` is an `IQuerable` anyway. You can also just combine the queries:

```
var finalQuery = BoughtItemDB.BoughtItems
                             .GroupBy(item => item.ItemCategory);
                             .Select(g => new 
                              { 
                                  ItemCategory = g.Key, 
                                  Cost = g.Sum(x => x.ItemAmount)
                              });
```

Comment: The error he is getting is adding to `ObservableCollection`. He needs the select statement to return list of `MoneySpent`

Comment: Same response as the above post highlighting the error; Explicit construction of entity type 'WP7_CashTrack.DBControl+MoneySpent' in query is not allowed.  Is it because the constructor thinks it has already been defined?

Comment: @MarkOates: You cannot project to an entity in Linq to Entities - my query projects to an anonymous class instead - are you sure you are using this query? You should define a new class instead that you project to, and use that as the type within your `ObservableCollection`

Comment: @BrokenGlass I;m not sure I follow you do on this.  I think I need to create a new class (eg CatSummary) but I'm not sure how I project my new summary data to it?