# Load some data for props using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explicit construction of entity type [MyClass] in query is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952856/explicit-construction-of-entity-type-myclass-in-query-is-not-allowed)

I am using linq to sql - I am trying to get the count for 2 props below (open and closed tasks) however I get an exception saying I cannot load the entity in query, how can I achieve this?

my code:

```
var milestones = ReadOnlySession.All<Milestone>()
    .Where(x => x.InstructionID == instructionid)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new Milestone
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        InstructionID = x.InstructionID,
        Body = x.Body,
        Deadline = x.Deadline,
        MilestoneID = x.MilestoneID,
        TotalClosedTasks = 
            ReadOnlySession.All<InstructionTask>()
            .Count(c => c.Milestone == x.MilestoneID && !c.IsOpen),
        TotalOpenTasks = 
            ReadOnlySession.All<InstructionTask>()
            .Count(c => c.Milestone == x.MilestoneID && c.IsOpen)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Error:

Message :Explicit construction of entity type 'Surventrix.Domain.Model.Entities.Milestone' in query is not allowed.

Source :System.Data.Linq

Note:
**ReadOnlySession** - abstraction over the data context, provides me with All, Single (basically get all entities of T)

Answer (score 0):

try to add AsEnumerable after order clause, this shoudl solve the issue, if you don't have performance issues.

```
var milestones = ReadOnlySession.All<Milestone>()
.Where(x => x.InstructionID == instructionid)
.OrderBy(x => x.Name).AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new Milestone
{
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to separate the creation of the Milestone objects (where you also set the extra total closed/open tasks properties) from the query. In the query below an anonymous object from the db, and afterwards* new Milestone objects are created. This way, it is still a single query, assuming the ReadOnlySession still returns IQueryable's.

```
var milestones = ReadOnlySession.All<Milestone>()
    .Where(x => x.InstructionID == instructionid)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new { 
        Milestone = x,
        TotalClosedTasks = ReadOnlySession.All<InstructionTask>()
                                .Count(c => c.Milestone == x.MilestoneID && !c.IsOpen)
        TotalOpenTasks = ReadOnlySession.All<InstructionTask>()
                                .Count(c => c.Milestone == x.MilestoneID && c.IsOpen)
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new Milestone {
        Name = x.Milestone.Name,
        InstructionID = x.Milestone.InstructionID,
        Body = x.Milestone.Body,
        Deadline = x.Milestone.Deadline,
        MilestoneID = x.Milestone.MilestoneID,
        TotalClosedTasks = x.TotalClosedTasks,
        TotalOpenTasks = x.TotalOpenTask
    })
    .ToList();
```