# Explicit construction of entity type 'tblpayment' in query is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, linq

I wrote a common query in my web application using linq but after executing i got this error :

```
Explicit construction of entity type 'AccidentCongress.dblinqtoDb.tblpayment' in query is not allowed.
```

My query is :

```
public List<tblpayment> returnpay(string uname)
    {
        List<tblpayment> q = (from i in db.tblpayments
                              where i.ownerUsername == uname
                              select new tblpayment
                                  {
                                      id = i.id
                                  }).ToList();
        return q;
    }
```

I searched this problem but i couldn't find any useful solution.

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good explanation of the exception here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953058/59849

Are you sure you need to construct a new instance of `tblpayment` in your query? Can you just do something like this:

```
public List<tblpayment> returnpay(string uname)
{
    List<tblpayment> q = (from i in db.tblpayments
                          where i.ownerUsername == uname
                          select i).ToList();
    return q;
}
```

If you really do need to create a new list of `tblpayment` objects based on your query, you could do it like this:

```
public List<tblpayment> returnpay(string uname)
{
    List<tblpayment> q = (from i in db.tblpayments
                          where i.ownerUsername == uname
                          select i).ToList();

    return q.Select(x => new tblpayment { id = i.id }).ToList();
}
```