# LINQ to SQL - Get only substring from a field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm studying ASP.NET MVC and I use LINQ to SQL for model.

I have a table named "Note" with the fields "Title" and "Content". The "Content" field can contain thousand characters.

What I want to do is to display the LIST of notes in a page. I use table with two columns, for "Title" and SUBSTRING of the "Content" (50 characters). My problem is, I don't know how to edit the model so that it will display only the substring of the "Content".

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I tried this codes:

```
        List<Note> notes = (from n in databaseModel.Notes
                           select new Note
                           {
                               ID = n.ID,
                               Title = n.Title,
                               Content = n.Content.Substring(0,50),
                               DateCreated = n.DateCreated,
                               DateModified = n.DateModified
                           }).ToList();
```

but gives me error:

```
Explicit construction of entity type 'domanokz.Models.Note' in query is not allowed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a view of the table with one field truncated. I used the view to create class instead.

Answer (score 2):

1 example worth 20 explains - look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737939#strsubst)

```
var result=from x in Contents
   select new
   {
       Content = x.Content.Substring(0,50)
   }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, new to LINQ also. Can you translate it to SQL?

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING (Content,1,50)

Comment: @yytg I get it now, I just change the Contents to Note as it was the name of the table. Now, I'm getting this error.

Comment: @yytg - I put it in my question.

Comment: @domanokz The problem is so you not allowed to do 'select new Note
' look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787296/explicit-construction-of-entity-type-in-query-is-not-allowed

Comment: @domanokz Try to create a new class so inherit the 'Note
' class - and use it for this query (I'm not sure about it)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out... Figured it out as not possible. I created a view and used it instead of the table. Thanks for help anyway.