# Issue with initializing new object in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

This code builds without problems but fails when executed:

```
var query =
    _db.STEWARDSHIP
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.VisitDate)
        .Where(r => SiteId == null || r.SiteAssoc.Id == iSiteId)
        .Where(r => r.MarkedForDeletion == false)
        .Select(r => new SearchResults(r.Id, 
                                       r.SiteAssoc.Name, 
                                       r.VisitDate, 
                                       r.VisitTypeValAssoc.Description));
```

The error message is:

`Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.`

What am I doing wrong here? I must pass info to the constructor to build the SearchResults objects. Is there a way to do this or do I have to make this a 2-step thing where I get the results and then iterate over the results to create the new objects?

**UPDATE:**

Changing the select to this fixes the issue:

```
 .Select(r => new SearchResults(){Id = r.Id, 
                                 Name = r.SiteAssoc.Name, 
                                 VisitDate = r.VisitDate, 
                                 VisitType = r.VisitTypeValAssoc.Description});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 .OrderByDescending(r => r.VisitDate)
        .Where(r => SiteId == null || r.SiteAssoc.Id == iSiteId)
        .Where(r => r.MarkedForDeletion == false)
        .Select(r => new SearchResults()
                                       {
                                       ID = Ir.Id, 
                                       Name = r.SiteAssoc.Name, 
                                       VisitDate = r.VisitDate, 
                                       Description = r.VisitTypeValAssoc.Description
                                       });
```

Comment: Haris, that did not work, I get that Id, Name, etc does not exist in current context.

Comment: You should replace `ID`, `Name` etc with actual property name of your `SeachResults` class

Answer (score 1):

> Entities can be created outside of queries and inserted into the data
>   store using a DataContext. You can then retrieve them using queries.
>   However, you can't create entities as part of a query.

See this post [Explicit construction of entity type '###' in query is not allowed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787296/explicit-construction-of-entity-type-in-query-is-not-allowed)

LINQ doesn't allow the explicit construction of objects within the select statements.

Comment: Thanks for the link. While review the answers, I saw this: `c => new AttachmentCulture { Culture = c };` and when I translate into my example, it works. See the note I added to the orignal post.